# Cómo puedo buscar texto en archivos HTML locales?

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript

Estoy realizando una app que contiene un array de elementos.

```js
arrLista: any;

arrLista = [
  {
   nombre:  'The Beatles',
   archivo: 'assets/html/beatles.html' 
  },
  {
   nombre:  'Nirvana',
   archivo: 'assets/html/nirvana.html' 
  },
  {
   nombre:  'The Doors',
   archivo: 'assets/html/thedoors.html' 
  }
];

  getNombre(cadena){
    return this.arrLista.filter((item) => {
      return item.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(
       cadena.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  }
```

Me gustaría realizar la búsqueda por el contenido del archivo que se encuentra en "archivo" dentro del array. El array siempre va a tener elementos fijos.

Por ejemplo, me van escribiendo "The" y que eso sólo lo busque en el contenido del archivo.
He visto ejemplos con FileReader() pero no me entero muy bien.

Tal cual tengo la de buscar el nombre del item pero con el contenido.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: De sobra una coma en cuando termina la posición de The doors. y posiblemente tengas mas errores de sintaxis

Comment: quieres buscar frases en un array de string?

Comment: puedes ejecutar un servicio get donde el return es un html, recuerda que para eso sirve el content-type puedes ver la [lista](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Lista_completa_de_tipos_MIME)

Answer (score 1):

Para buscar en objetos de un array, te dejo un método muy básico, usando test(); esto te devuelve todos los archivos que contengan la entrada que le pongas.

```js
var arrLista = [
    {
     nombre:  'The Beatles',
     archivo: 'assets/html/beatles.html' 
    },
    {
     nombre:  'Nirvana',
     archivo: 'assets/html/nirvana.html' 
    },
    {
     nombre:  'The Doors',
     archivo: 'assets/html/thedoors.html' 
    }
  ];


function busca(str){

    archivo = [];

    var patt = new RegExp(str);

    arrLista.forEach(e=>{
        if(patt.test(e.nombre)) archivo.push(e.archivo);
    });

    return archivo;
}


console.log(busca("The"))
```

Si los archivos que quieres leer están en tu servidor, lo que creo que necesitas es hacer simplemente ajax.

```js
var contenido = document.getElementById("contenido")

var xhttp;
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    contenido.innerHTML = "Esto emula la lectura de un archivo --->"+this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

```html
<div id="contenido">

</div>
```

Si quieres leer archivos locales del cliente, te dejo un ejemplo de como usar [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader) , pero esto solo lee archivos locales que el usuario específicamente subió. Corre el código de abajo y selecciona un archivo de texto.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var archivoSubido = document.getElementById('archivoASubir');
  var contenido = document.getElementById('contenido');

  archivoSubido.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   var file = archivoSubido.files[0];
          
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
     contenido.innerText = reader.result;
    }

    reader.readAsText(file); 
   
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="archivoASubir">


<div id="contenido">
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Los archivos están dentro de la app, en cliente, ya que es una app de IONIC. 
Lo que no sé es cómo aplicar la búsqueda al contenido de los archivos a los que "apunto" desde el array. Tal y como lo tengo con el atributo "nombre".

Comment: @bitelmaniaco bueno, esto es javascript puro, supongo que no es muy práctico pedirle al usuario que seleccione el/los archivos en donde quiere buscar, supongo. Con el tema de IONIC no estoy seguro, pero si la aplicación corre nativa en un móvil supongamos, puedes ahorrate ese paso de la selección usando ajax. Porque para el motor javascript sería el mismo origen.

Comment: Exacto, no es nada cómodo. Por eso guardo en un array tanto el "título" como la "ruta" de la página donde YO he guardado pues un HTML con información por cada grupo.

Si te fijas, al principio, hay una función "getNombre(cadena)" que llamo desde la Page que no es más que una búsqueda de un string dentro de un string.
Lo que quiero es lo mismo pero dentro de un archivo HTML.

Comment: si quieres leer un archivo igual lo tienes que hacer la llamada de un servicio rest, la difeencia es que defines el conten-type html y listo

Comment: @JackNavaRow si, es verdad, esa es la otra posibilidad, si es distinto origen hay que hacer un request desde el servidor.